# No such column exists error when inserting into sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am having trouble inserting records to my application local database. I am getting data from web services and tried to store them inside my app local sqlite database but i am getting no such table error.
This is the code of my DatabaseHelper class that i am using for table creation & inserting into it.

```
private static final String CREATE_MERCHANT_DETAILS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MERCHANT_DETAILS + 
    " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
    KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " 
    + KEY_LOGO + "TEXT, " 
    + KEY_BACKGROUND + "TEXT, " 
    + KEY_PRODUCT + "TEXT, " 
    + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + "TEXT, " 
    + KEY_TYPE + "TEXT, " 
    + KEY_DENOMINATION + "TEXT);";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_MERCHANT_DETAILS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void insertAMerchant(String name, String logo, String background, String product, String productId, String type, String denomination) {
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(KEY_LOGO, logo);
        contentValues.put(KEY_BACKGROUND, background);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT, product);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID, productId);
        contentValues.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
        contentValues.put(KEY_DENOMINATION, denomination);
        database.insert(TABLE_MERCHANT_DETAILS, null, contentValues);
    }
```

Comment: CREATE_MERCHANT_DETAILS, code?

Comment: private static final String CREATE_MERCHANT_DETAILS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MERCHANT_DETAILS + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_LOGO + "TEXT, " + KEY_BACKGROUND + "TEXT, " + KEY_PRODUCT + "TEXT, " + KEY_PRODUCT_ID + "TEXT, " + KEY_TYPE + "TEXT, " + KEY_DENOMINATION + "TEXT);";

Comment: Check out : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 2):

Add spaces between your column names and types in your `CREATE TABLE` SQL.

Uninstall your app so that the old database file gets removed and your `onCreate()` is run again.

Comment: Your trick works for me at once but now when i run my app again without uninstalling it stores same database records again & again taking from web services. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Don't write the same records again, or add `UNIQUE` constraint to those columns that should have unique values.

Comment: I have tried adding unique constraint to KEY_NAME column but it is inserting same records everytime i run the app.

Comment: After changing the schema you need to recreate the table by e.g. uninstalling the app.

Comment: Instead of uninstalling the app every time when you change Schema, you can increment DB Version and implement `onUpgrade`. I've added the code how to do in my answer. pl check it out.

Comment: Thankyou @laalto u helped me a lot. I think you are a helpfull guy.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says,

> No such column exists error when inserting into sqlite database

and in your question you're saying,

> no such table error.

If the error is `No such column exists`, the problem can be because of

1. Spacing between the column name and Type
2. **If you have changed your Table Schema** then you need to increment your `DATABASE_VERSION` to reflect the change. But, you need to implement and setup `onUpgrade` to do so. I've added code here.

You need to setup `onUpgrade` to reflect the new changes. You can do by,

```
 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "on Upgrade is called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MERCHANT_DETAILS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

To check whether your Sql query is valid/not, print the query in the
`DatabaseHelper.`

```
System.out.println(CREATE_MERCHANT_DETAILS);
```

This will display the query and you can check exactly where you made the mistake.